# Is bonus 100 reputation real?

Tags: bug, reputation, answers, protected-questions, association-bonus

I have 101 reputation on AskUbuntu (1 initial plus 100 bonus as I've reached 200 on StackOverflow). I wanted to add answer for [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/574569/apt-get-stuck-at-0-connecting-to-us-archive-ubuntu-com) question, it requires 10 reputation minimum on that site as stated on that page below answers. But I couldn't post my answer.  Is it a bug? Or do I need 10 non-bonus reputation on that site? Or am I missing something that caused such a restriction for me?

Comment: 10 non-bonus reputation on that site is it. The message says "on this site".

Comment: @PeterJ it's not obvious. For me it looked like I had 1 reputation "on this site", than I reached 200 on SO and as a bonus I gained 100 bonus reputation also "on this site". It is absolutely not obvious that if you have 101 reputation on top of page, then it means that you have 1 reputation "on this site" and 100 somewhere else. However thank you for clarification